# Why does my replace work properly in javascript when I use "and" or "or" but not when I use "&" or "/" or "+"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a first name input in a HTML form and sometimes a user will input two first names and I need to strip out the second name and the word or character used to join them. If I use the word "and" or the word "or" my javascript works fine and strips out the second name and the word used to join them. However, if I use an ampersand (&) or a plus sign (+) or a forward slash (/), no matter how I code it, it will only strip out the last character of the second name and not the joining character or any af the second name except the last character.

I have tried using string functions, regular expressions, testing my regular expression at regex.com (they work there and properly select the words and the joining words), a dozen different variations of my regular expression that all work properly at regex, com to select the text I want removed, but none of this works in my actual form.

For instance if I input:
"Bob and Dave" I get "Bob" - Correct
"Bob or Dave" I get "Bob" - Correct

But if I input: 
"Bob & Dave" I get "Bob & Dav" - Incorrect
"Bob + Dave" I get "Bob + Dav" - Incorrect
"Bob / Dave" I get "Bob " -  Incorrect but Acceptable
"Bob, Dave"  I get "Bob, Dav" - Incorrect

This is some of the code I have used, several different approaches have worked for the first two, nothing has worked for the last four.

Works for "Bob and Dave":

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search(/(\s)*\w+/gi)
var x = pattern.search("AND", z+1)
if (z < x) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME')
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value=pattern.replace(/\s(AND)*\w+/gi, "");
}
}
```

Works for "Bob or Dave":

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search(/\s(OR)*\w+/gi)
var x = pattern.search("OR", z+1)
if (z < x) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME')
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value=pattern.replace(/\s(or)*\w+/gi, "");
}
}
```

This also worked for "Bob and Dave" and changing the corresponding word "and" for "or", worked for "Bob or Dave":

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search("and")
var x = pattern.search("and")
if (z < x) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME')
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value=pattern.slice(0, z);
}
}
```

However, this worked for the incorrect but acceptable "Bob, Dave", but did not work for "Bob & Dave" or "Bob / Dave", when the appropriate characters were substituted:

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search(/(,\s+)/gi);
var x = pattern.search((/(,\s+)/gi), z-1);
if (z < x) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME');
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value=pattern.replace(/(,\s+)/gi);
}
}
```

And this yielded the same incorrect result with "&" and "/":

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search(/(\s&)/gi);
var x = pattern.search(/(\s&\s.[a-z].+)/gi, z-1);
if (x < z) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME');
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value=pattern.replace(/(\s&\s.[a-z].+)/gi, "");
}
}
```

The regular expressions all worked to select the proper text at regex.com, but never work in my form and I am almost out of hair to pull in frustration.

Why is this happening and more importantly how can I fix it. I have tried several other solutions I found on this site such as:

```
function noExtraNames() {
var pattern=document.forms[0].first_name.value;
var z = pattern.search(/(,\s+)/gi);
var x = pattern.search((/(,\s+)/gi), z-1);
if (x < z) {
    alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME');
    document.forms[0].first_name.focus();
    var s = document.forms[0].first_name.value;
    var n = s.indexOf('&');
    s = s.substring(0, n != -1 & n : s.length);
    return document.forms[0].first_name.value = s;
}
}
```

All for no joy.

The expected output is: Bob
The actual output is: Bob & Dav

Comment: Do you want to remove all from the first space? `return document.forms[0].first_name.value.replace(/\s.*/, '')`?

Comment: [This is probably relevant here](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). The name `Jones, Tom` should be valid for `Tom Jones`. Also, are you saying that the tennis player Igor **And**reev shouldn't be using his name? What about George **Or**well?

Comment: That `z-1` on the second search means you find the same string again, so your `x` will always equal `z`. (Except when the string is not found, which you never test for)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this would be better handled by splitting on the regex and returning the first item. This pattern should take care of the cases mentioned in your post:

```
var pattern = /(\s*[\+|&|\,|\/]\s*|\s+(and|or)\s+)/i;
```

then splitting and always returning the first element.

```js
function noExtraNames(name) {
  var pattern = /(\s*[\+|&|\,|\/]\s*|\s+(and|or)\s+)/i;
  var items = name.split(pattern);
  if (items.length > 1) {
    console.log('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME');
    return items[0];
  }
  return name;
}

let tests = [
  'Bob',
  'Billy Bob',
  'Bob and Dave',
  'Bob + Dave',
  'Bob & Dave',
  'Bob / Dave',
  'Bob, Dave',
  'Igor',
  'Andy',
  'Bob+Dave',
];

for (let test of tests) {
  console.log(test, '===> ', noExtraNames(test));
}
```

Comment: This fails for someone named Igor. It only outputs "Ig"

Comment: Updated pattern then, checks for spaces around `and` and `or`, otherwise no spaces needed

Answer (score 0):

```
const pattern = /(.*(?=(\s+(and|or)\s+)|(\s*[\&\+,\/\\])))|.*/i;
const patternMatch = str.match(pattern);
if (patternMatch[1]) {
  alert('Please only enter ONLY ONE FIRST NAME');
}
const replaceValue = patternMatch[0].trim();
document.forms[0].first_name.value = replaceValue;
```

I guess that's what you need.